# Customized Function for error logs Scripting

Tags: shell, ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh
DateForFileName=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S`
DateTimeForLog=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p")
StdOutPutlogFile='/tmp/Suganya/LofFileCheck'
StdErrorLogFile='/tmp/Suganya/LofFileCheckError'
ScriptName=$(basename $0 | cut -d'.' -f1)
#function to capture common error logs with timestamp
OutputLog()
 {
  read IN
  echo $DateTimeForLog-$ScriptName-"Information"-$IN >> $StdOutPutlogFile
 }
errorLog()
{
 read IN
 echo "error"
 echo $DateTimeForLog-$ScriptName-"Error"-$IN >> $StdErrorLogFile
 }
Customoutput()
 {
 echo $DateTimeForLog-$ScriptName-"Information"-$1 >> $StdOutPutlogFile
 }
#######set of commands#########
{
echo 'started'
ls -la
cd /tmp/kjhdakdha
ls -la
} 2> errorLog 1> OutputLog
```

I am trying to capture the error logs and output logs separately using customized function for the set of commands. But it is not calling the userdefined function actually. Instead, it is creating the file "errorLog" and "outputLog". Kindly help to call the function for the set of commands to capture the logs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to actually *run* those functions... `$(errorLog)` for example, however you're echoing two things as output and additionally redirecting to completely separate  files, so what are you trying to write to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function with arguments, so that it can take the error logs accordingly and print as per the commands within it, please see the corrected one below,

```
    #!/bin/ksh
    DateForFileName=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S`
    DateTimeForLog=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p")
    StdOutPutlogFile='/tmp/Suganya/LofFileCheck'
    StdErrorLogFile='/tmp/Suganya/LofFileCheckError'
    ScriptName=$(basename $0 | cut -d'.' -f1)
    #function to capture common error logs with timestamp
    OutputLog()
     {
      echo $DateTimeForLog-$ScriptName-"Information"-$1>> $StdOutPutlogFile
     }
    errorLog()
    {
     echo "error"
     echo $DateTimeForLog-$ScriptName-"Error"-$1>> $StdErrorLogFile
     }
    Customoutput()
     {
     echo $DateTimeForLog-$ScriptName-"Information"-$1 >> $StdOutPutlogFile
     }
    #######set of commands#########
    {
    echo 'started'
    ls -la
    cd /tmp/kjhdakdha
    ls -la
    } 2> errorLog.txt 1> OutputLog.txt
    if [ -s errorLog.txt ];then
        LE=`cat errorLog.txt`
        errorLog "$LE"
    fi
    if [ -s OutputLog.txt ];then
        LO=`cat OutputLog`
        OutputLog "$LO"
    fi
rm errorLog.txt OutputLog.txt
```